# Is it OK to write down Torah verses in script form?

Tags: halacha

I was writing down verses from the Torah using Hebrew script form, and was told by someone that I should be writing them as block letters.

Then I asked someone else another day and he said I didn't need to do that.

I'm just writing them down to learn/memorize individual passages, not copying the entire text.

Is it OK to write them in script form?

Comment: They will still be sheimos, regardless of how they are written

Answer (score 1):

There used reason to say that one can only write Torah She'b'ksav (the Bible) in regular block letters, but Chazal instituted the rule of עת לעשות לה' הפר תורתך and permitted other forms as well (and also the writing of Torah She'bal Peh (the Talmud, and other texts). See the Mishna Berura and Aruch Hashulchan in Orach Chayim 334:12.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought eis laasos was only for writing down Torah shebaal peh.

Answer (score -1):

You could write them in any form you want - there is no reason you should have to write them in block form, and not script.

Comment: This is mistaken.

Comment: @DoubleAA Oh? How?

Comment: This answer would be much more useful with a source - where do you know this from?